# What is the difference between Ubuntu Software Centre and Synaptic Package Manager?

Tags: package-management, software-center, synaptic

I am transferring from 8.10 to 10.10. I was wondering what is the difference between Ubuntu Software Centre and Synaptic Package Manager in 10.10? For what kinds of things do I need to go which?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both of them are package managers. Software center is simple to use, but synaptic is more complicated and provides more options (more details about packages for example). Synaptic will be removed from Ubuntu soon (but still available to install) since software center can do the work ([here](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/09/synaptic-is-going-bye-bye-soon.html)).

Answer (score 11):

Syanptic is more powerful and was designed as a **package manager**. Software Center was designed as an "**app-store"** like program.

Comment: I'd add that synaptic is an advanced tool and you can break something if you don't know what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

In synaptic package manager you can select several packages and install at once.

But in Software Center you cannot do that. You have to select one and click on `install` and then only can select the next.