# How do I lock a package in the Software Centre?

Tags: package-management, software-center, gui, updates

I know that you can lock a package using the command line and synaptic - is there a way to do so using the Software Centre?

Comment: Doubt it, USC is supposed to be simpler than Synaptic.

Comment: Which **Ubuntu** version?  11.10, 11.04, 10.10, etc.

Comment: No, just looking for clarity.

Comment: 11.10 was the version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Software Center is [an application manager, not a package manager](https://askubuntu.com/q/25728/24694), and as such does not provide advanced functionality like version locking. Unfortunately, your question is analogous to asking how to perform differential calculus in a children's math game.

If you **do** want this functionality, you should install the [*Synaptic Package Manager*](http://www.nongnu.org/synaptic/) [image: (install)] and follow the instructions from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/18654/24694).

Comment: Thanks for this - I don't myself use the Software Centre - was asking for someone else.